# PHP error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime

I was looking for an answer for a long time. I am new to PHP and I am trying to insert current date and time into database table column of type datetime. However it gives me the error.

```
$tsql ="INSERT INTO metaTagsTable (Email,nMetaTheme,nMetaSpecification,sMetaDuration,nChildrenYearTo,nChildrenYearFrom,nMetaPaxChildren,nMetaPax,dMetaReturnDate,dMetaDepartureDate, nMetaDestinationSubArea,nMetaDestinationArea,nMetaDestinationCountry,nMetaDestination,nMetaDepartureSubArea,nMetaDepartureArea,nMetaDepartureCountry,nMetaDeparture,sMetaCategory,ModifiedDate,dCreatedDate,nSupplierId,VisitorID) VALUES ('".$array[0]."','".$array[1]."','".$array[2]."','".$array[3]."','".$array[4]."','".$array[5]."','".$array[6]."','".$array[7]."',
'".$array[8]."','".$array[9]."','".$array[10]."','".$array[11]."','".$array[12]."','".$array[13]."','".$array[14]."','".$array[15]."','".$array[16]."','".$array[17]."','".$array[18]."',getdate(),getdate(),'".$array[21]."','".$array[22]."')";
```

Array has is made from this input:

```
test;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;null;"499366";null;null;null;null;null;"Catalogue";null;null;null;null
```

Error:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 22007 [SQLSTATE] => 22007 [1] => 241 [code] => 241 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. ) )
```

Table design:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[metaTagsTableTMP](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[nMetaTheme] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[nMetaSpecification] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[sMetaDuration] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[nChildrenYearTo] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[nChildrenYearFrom] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[nMetaPaxChildren] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[nMetaPax] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[dMetaReturnDate] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[dMetaDepartureDate] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[nMetaDestinationSubArea] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[nMetaDestinationArea] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[nMetaDestinationCountry] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[nMetaDestination] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[nMetaDepartureSubArea] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[nMetaDepartureArea] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[nMetaDepartureCountry] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[nMetaDeparture] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[sMetaCategory] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[dCreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[nSupplierId] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[VisitorID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_metaTagsTableTMP] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Comment: please could you post the contents of your $array so we can see what is being passed to the INSERT query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't think of `getdate()` as a method, I don't know why. So I didn't put right quotes.
This is the correct query:

```
$tsql ="INSERT INTO metaTagsTable (Email,nMetaTheme,nMetaSpecification,sMetaDuration,nChildrenYearTo,nChildrenYearFrom,nMetaPaxChildren,nMetaPax,dMetaReturnDate,dMetaDepartureDate, nMetaDestinationSubArea,nMetaDestinationArea,nMetaDestinationCountry,nMetaDestination,nMetaDepartureSubArea,nMetaDepartureArea,nMetaDepartureCountry,nMetaDeparture,sMetaCategory,ModifiedDate,dCreatedDate,nSupplierId,VisitorID) VALUES ('".$array[0]."','".$array[1]."','".$array[2]."','".$array[3]."','".$array[4]."','".$array[5]."','".$array[6]."','".$array[7]."','".$array[8]."','".$array[9]."','".$array[10]."','".$array[11]."','".$array[12]."','".$array[13]."','".$array[14]."','".$array[15]."','".$array[16]."','".$array[17]."','".$array[18]."',".getdate().",".getdate().",'".$array[21]."','".$array[22]."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

SqlDateTime expects the dateTime parameter in the following format if it is a string::

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: Thx, but why it should be string? I am not inserting any string by doing the query right?

Comment: Can you debug the generated INSERT statement, the MsSQL error suggests it is receiving an unknown string format; I suspect you are trying to insert an empty string. What API are you using to generate and execute this query ?

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look a little later since I cant access to server right now ;/. I think its pretty standard API = first google search PHP mssql query ... :D